# SQL Server Select from table where primary key does not appear as foreign key in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables -

```
User                UserID PK

SecurityGroup       SecurityGroupID PK, SecurityGroupName

UserSecurityGroup   UserSecurityGroupID, UserID FK, SecurityGroupID FK
```

I am trying to select the names of the security groups that a user is NOT a part of.

A user can be a member of more than one group.

i.e. I have three security groups: Admin, Moderator, Member

I pass through a UserID. Said user is assigned to the Admin and Moderator groups but is NOT part of the Member group. I'm trying to display "Member".

These are my attempts so far:

**Attempt 1 -**

```
select tblSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupName
from tblSecurityGroup
    inner join tblUserSecurityGroup
        on tblSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupID = tblUserSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupID
    inner join tblUser
        on tblUserSecurityGroup.UserID = tblUser.UserID
where tblUser.UserID = 1
    and tblSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupID not in (tblUserSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupID);
```

**Attempt 2 -**

```
select tblSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupName
from tblSecurityGroup
    inner join tblUserSecurityGroup
        on tblSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupID = tblUserSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupID
    inner join tblUser
        on tblUserSecurityGroup.UserID = tblUser.UserID
where tblUser.UserID = 1
    and not exists (select tblSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupID
                    from tblSecurityGroup
                    where tblUserSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupID = tblSecurityGroup.SecurityGroupID);
```

Guidance for a nooby student would be most appreciated.

Comment: What were the results of these attempts?

Comment: Running my queries IN FULL doesn't bring back anything. Running each attempt EXCLUDING the last line brings back the security groups that the user is a part of.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: Apologies, tags have been revised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question can be answered by a `not exists` query.  Here is one method:

```
select sg.SecurityGroupName
from tblSecurityGroup sg
where not exists (select 1
                  from tblUserSecurityGroup usg 
                  where sg.SecurityGroupID = usg.SecurityGroupID and
                        usg.UserID = 1
                 );
```

Note that `tblUser` is not needed because `UserID` is in `tblUserSecurityGroup`.

Comment: Thanks! Works a treat.